# Else Statement returned Blank in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to implement a simple search on my Laravel Application

```
public function search()
{
    $search = request()->query('search');
    if ($search) {
        $books = Book::where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")->simplepaginate(12);
    }
    else {
        echo "<h2>Book Not Found, please try using another search term</h2>";
        $books = Book::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->simplepaginate(12);
    }
    return view('search')->with('books', $books);        
}
```

But the else returned a blank screen when the search terms can't be found

## UPDATE

Here is my `view` file

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 offset-md-1">
            <div class="row">

            @foreach($books as $book)

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="home-catalog-image">
                <a href="{{ route('book', $book->id) }}" target="_blank">
        <!--  <img src="{{ $book->image }}" alt="trending image" /> -->
            <img src="{{ $book->image_url }}" class="img-responsive" alt="{{$book->image_url}}">

            </a>
                </div>
                <p class="author">{{ $book->author->name }}</p>
                <h1 class="book-title">{{str_limit($book -> name, 20) }}</h1>
            </div>
            @endforeach

            </div>
            <p style="text-align:center;>"> {!! $books->render() !!} </p>

        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Don't put the html tag in your controller, put them in view

Comment: I don't think the condition is falling inside the else block, because if it does, then nothing should stop the echo from working! you can try Logging your code if it's entering the else statement.

Comment: perhaps there was an exception that's skips the whole block of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem, I use `forelse` instead of `foreach` a

```
            @forelse($books as $book)

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="home-catalog-image">
                <a href="{{ route('book', $book->id) }}" target="_blank">
        <!--  <img src="{{ $book->image }}" alt="trending image" /> -->
            <img src="{{ $book->image_url }}" class="img-responsive" alt="{{$book->image_url}}">

            </a>
                </div>
                <p class="author">{{ $book->author->name }}</p>
                <h1 class="book-title">{{str_limit($book -> name, 20) }}</h1>
            </div>
            @empty

<h2>Book Not Found, please try using another search term</h2>
            @endforelse
```

In my controller, I used

```
public function search()
{
    $search = request('search', null);

    $books = Book::when($search, function ($query, $search) {
                        return $query->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%");
                    })
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                    ->simplePaginate(12);

        return view('search')->with('books', $books);        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check how to use the [request()](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-request) helper to get the input.

Also  you can use [when()](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#conditional-clauses)  method for conditional clauses instead `if` `else`.

```
public function search()
{
    $search = request('search', null);

    $books = Book::when($search, function ($query, $search) {
                    return $query->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%");
                })
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                ->simplePaginate(12);

    return view('search')->with('books', $books);        
}
```

Then in Blade you can use [@forelse](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#loops) directive to loop the collection, or if it's empty, show the message.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 offset-md-1">
            <div class="row">
            @forelse ($books as $book)
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="home-catalog-image">
                        <a href="{{ route('book', $book->id) }}" target="_blank">
                            <!--  <img src="{{ $book->image }}" alt="trending image" /> -->
                            <img src="{{ $book->image_url }}" class="img-responsive" alt="{{$book->image_url}}">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <p class="author">{{ $book->author->name }}</p>
                    <h1 class="book-title">{{str_limit($book -> name, 20) }}</h1>
                </div>
            @empty
                <h2>Book Not Found, please try using another search term</h2>
            @endforelse
            </div>
            <p style="text-align:center;>"> {!! $books->render() !!} </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Somehow, this didn't work for, I figured it myself 
`@forelse($books as $book)
.
@empty
.
@endforelse

Comment: Oh yes, @forelse for collections. So the query works?